# C++ array with variable length wouldn't work

Tags: c++

```
/*Print the first N prime numbers based on user input*/

#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int N) {
   if (N <= 0) {return false;}
   double L = sqrt(N);
   for (int i=2; i<=L; i++) {
      if (N%i == 0) {return false;}
   }
   return true;
}

int main()
{
   int Q = 0;  //# of prime numbers to be found
   int C = 0;  //That's the counter
   int I = 2;  //Number to be check
   cout<<"Number of prime numbers needed: ";
   cin>>Q;

   int primes [Q];

   while (true) {
      if (C == Q) {break;}
      if (isPrime(I)) {
         primes[C] = I;
         C++;
         I++;
      }
   }

   for (int i=0; i<Q; i++) {
      cout<<primes[i]<<endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This does not work and always print 2 and 1 to the screen instead of a list of prime numbers, the isPrime function does work well, probably something wrong with my array

Comment: variable size array is not standard C++, I recommend using `std::vector` instead

Comment: Are you sure you want to increment I only if it's prime?

Comment: 2 and 1? I get at most 2 and 3 – three primes or more give an endless loop.

Comment: Variable sized arrays whose size comes form user input - as well as being unstandard - are also dangerous because your user could cause the stack to overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I` will increment only when prime condition is true, increment it outside if clause:

```
while (true) {
    if (C == Q) {break;}
    if (isPrime(I)) {
        primes[C] = I;
        C++;
    }
    I++;  //here
}
```

> C++ array with variable length wouldn't work

It works until `c` variable dosn't crosses integer range or array size the stack frame.

Comment: Variable length arrays are non-standard. As such they only work on some compilers. This won't compile under Visual Studio, for example (unless that's changed  recently) but will with g++. In other words, use with caution and don't count on portability.

Comment: @user4581301 since  user dosent mentioned any compiler error i answered based on that and agree with you in that case `vector<int>` is better...

Answer (score 0):

Your code in below line has compiler error

```
int primes [Q];
```

you must change this with below line

```
int *primes = new int[Q];
```

Comment: He could also use `std::vector<int> primes(Q);` and indeed probably should.

Comment: If recommending `new`, you should also explicitly mention the need to `delete` when finished and to guard against the unexpected.

Comment: Yes , before return 0; he must add delete[] primes;